# Angular 4 form [(ngModel)] error

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-ngmodel, angular4-forms

Im using `angular 4` with `meanstack`. My form shows an error when i type `[(ngModel)]`. then i tried `"ngmodel"` then the form works fine. but the data is undefined from the backend.

error as follows. 
when i use `[(ngModel)]`

```
<form (submit)="savereportdata()" novalidate>

<fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="middleItemId">Item ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Item ID" [(ngModel)]="itemid" name="itemid">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="middleItemId">type</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Item ID" [(ngModel)]="typeofdefect" name="typeofdefect">
    </div>
```

Error:

```
 VM3014 ReportComponent.ngfactory.js:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reportitemdata' of undefined
        at ReportComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/pages/requestreport/report/report.component.ts.ReportComponent.savereportdata (VM2980 main.bundle.js:983)
        at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (VM3014 ReportComponent.ngfactory.js:12)
        at handleEvent (VM2979 vendor.bundle.js:58441)
        at callWithDebugContext (VM2979 vendor.bundle.js:59905)
        at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (VM2979 vendor.bundle.js:59493)
        at dispatchEvent (VM2979 vendor.bundle.js:55034)
        at VM2979 vendor.bundle.js:55645
        at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (VM2979 vendor.bundle.js:64132)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM2976 polyfills.bundle.js:2970)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (VM2979 vendor.bundle.js:50300)
```

when i use `ngmodel`

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="middleItemId">Item ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Item ID" [(ngModel)]="itemid" name="itemid">
            </div>
```

Error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("Id">Item ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Item ID" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="itemid" name="itemid">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> "): ng:///AppModule/ReportComponent.html@6:80
        at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
        at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.es5.js:12932)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.es5.js:27126)
        at compiler.es5.js:27045
        at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js:27045)
        at compiler.es5.js:26932
        at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1683)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26931)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26860)
```

My `component.ts` file

```
import { NgModule,Component,Pipe,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReportserviceService } from '../../../service/reportservice.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})

export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  itemid:Number;
  typeofdefect:String;
  reportdescription:String;
  constructor() { }

public reportservice:ReportserviceService;


  ngOnInit() {
  }


  savereportdata(){   

  const reportitem = {
    itemid:this.itemid,
    typeofdefect:this.typeofdefect,
    reportdescription:this.reportdescription
  };


   this.reportservice.reportitemdata(reportitem).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res);
  }); 

  }

}
```

My `app.module.ts`file

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import{RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ReportserviceService } from './service/reportservice.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const applicationRoutes:Routes=[
{path:'report',component:ReportComponent},
{path:'requestexisting',component:ExistingitemComponent},
{path:'requestnew',component:NewitemComponent},
{path:'allocateproperties',component:AllocatepropertiesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    //more codes

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(applicationRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Ive been finding solutions for a whole month. but still couldnt solve it.

```
my @angular/cli:1.4.2
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
```

Comment: `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import{RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: edit your question and add the part where you are using reportitemdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the service inside the constructor

```
constructor(public reportservice:ReportserviceService) { }


//Add in app.module.ts
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
imports :[HttpModule]

//Add in service 
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
inject http in construtor like this
constructor(private http : Http);
```

Comment: `compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    `

Comment: can  you add your app.module.ts here?

Comment: add your service name into provider

Comment: and dont put ngModule inside ngModule (in imports) . Its a decorater we define other things inside it . But it shouldnt define itself

Comment: can you update the question with what you have done?

Comment: Whats the error and have you removed ngModule from imports inside the @ngModule -> imports [ngModule ](REmove this ngmodule not ouside one)

Comment: yes. i removed. and the errors are gone. but now my form does not show in the browser. only the theme and the nav bar

Comment: yes . when i enter **http://localhost:5000/report** it redirects to **http://localhost:5000** and this error shows up `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!
Error: No provider for Http!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at `